# How to connext mysql and piwigo with railway.app

Tags: mysql, docker, deployment, dockerfile

Hi I'm pretty new at deploying, but my task is to deploy piwigo and mysql on railway.app.

repo containing piwigo(i only use dockerfile and not docker-compose) :https://github.com/moritzheiber/piwigo-docker

usually locally i do these commands:

```
docker network create piwigo

docker run -d --name piwigo_mysql --network piwigo -e MYSQL_USER=piwigo -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=piwigo -e MYSQL_DATABASE=piwigo -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true mysql:8.0.18 --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

docker build -t piwigo-docker .

docker run -d --name piwigo --network piwigo -p 8000:8000 piwigo-docker
```

and it runs perfectly, how can i deploy online?